# Using regular expressions with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, capybara

In the below capybara test I want to check that a user can see any number after `'Temperature:'` when they visit the root path of my rails application. The value which is stored in the instance variable `@temperature` is retrieved from an API and is displayed to the user when the page is refreshed.

How can i put a ruby regular expression like `'Temperature: \d'` into my spec below?

**Spec:**

```
require "rails_helper"
feature "user sees temperature" do
  scenario "success" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_css 'p', text: 'Temperature: \d'
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
<p>Temperature: <%= @temperature %></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about right, you just have to use regex syntax (`//`) instead of string one (`''`):

```
expect(page).to have_css('p', text: /Temperature: \d/)
```

Comment: argh, so simple! Thanks @ndn!